# Восстановление доступа к ботам telegram после удаления аккаунта владельца

Tags: telegram

Telegram удалил мой аккаунт по таймингу(через пол года без активности), на этом аккаунте было несколько боевых ботов.

После удаления аккаунта боты не удалились но теперь я не пойму, как мне восстановить к ним доступ.

- Я пытался перерегистрироваться но на новом аккаунте список ботов пустой.
- Я писал в саппорт Telegram, уже 2 недели прошло а ответа от них нет.
- Искал подобную ситуацию в интернете но не нашел ничего похожего.

От безысходности пишу сюда.

Comment: Еще можно этот вопрос на английском стеке задать

Comment: Думаю вы правы, сейчас задам

Comment: Вопрос на английском стеке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613127/restoring-access-to-telegram-bots-after-deleting-the-owners-account

Comment: Ситуация на данный момент: telegram так и не ответил не по одному из каналов связи. Боты до сих пор работают но доступ к ним получить так и не удалось.